# Validation error if Import is not present in xtext

Tags: dsl, xtext, xtend, xtext-gradle-plugin

In my xtext grammar file to support wildcard import support, i have the following grammar rule.

```
Import:
   'import' importedNamespace= QualifiedNameWithWildcard  ';'
```

My requirement is i need to display the validation error if required dependency is not imported. for that i have added following code in grammar but while opening the project the validation error is displayed and disappeared in seconds.

```
TypeRef:
type=[Type |  QualifiedName ]
```

But if i have changed the QualifiedNameWithWildcard   with QualifiedName , i am able to show the validation error but wildcard import support is breaking. I have tried the following code it is not working.

```
Import:
   'import' importedNamespace= QualifiedName ';'

Import:
   'import' importedNamespace= QualifiedName | importedNamespace= QualifiedNameWithWildcard   ';'
```

Where am i going wrong?

can anyone please explain the following link:
[Eclipse Xtext Naming](http://www.euclideanspace.com/software/development/eclipse/xtext/infrastructure/naming/index.htm) where they have mentioned the follwing code is working. `Import returns EuclidImport :
'import' (
   importedNamespace=QualifiedName
  | importedNamespace=QualifiedNameWithWildCard) ';'?
;`

Comment: that is just a precedence thing. "a" "b" might be higher than |

Comment: but what is this about: about grammar and parsing or about writing the validator?

Comment: This is about, To show the validation error if required packages are imported.

Comment: But what is exactly not working for you

Comment: If i have added TypeRef:
type=[Type |  QualifiedName ]  i not getting validation error. Then if i added the following grammar change'import' (
   importedNamespace=QualifiedName
  | importedNamespace=QualifiedNameWithWildCard) ';'?
; i am getting validation error but wildcard import is not supported, it throws validation error in wildcard import statement.

Comment: In Xtext you don't get any validation error unless you write a validator. So which validation error do you talk about. How is it's message

Comment: Couldn't resolve reference to <function/variable name>. currently this validation error is displaying for other than library function/ variable if used any function/variable with out the required import. But for library function/variables no validation error is displayed even if we not imported required packages and during execution we are getting exception. Since we unable find the correct variable/function to execute.

Comment: how does your grammar look like. please not imports just make sstuff visible. if the stuff is visible already no import needed.

Comment: Sorry, i did't get you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181866/discussion-between-christian-dietrich-and-renganathan-selvaraju).